# RayCast won't return true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

So I'm new to c# and I'm trying to make a pong game in Unity, but for the life of me I can't figure out why the ray cast on lines 55 and 56 (first two lines of FixedUpdate) won't return true. The raycast against the walls work, but when using the exact same code, only changing what it's interacting with,it just doesn't return true.

"""

```
public GameObject ball;
public LayerMask player1Score;
public LayerMask player2Score;
public LayerMask walls;
public LayerMask Player;

public float Horizontal;
public float Vertical;

public bool player1Scored;
public bool player2Scored;

public Text player1Points;
public float player1Scores = 0;

public Text player2Points;
public float player2Scores = 0;



void Start()
{
    player1Scores = 0;
    player2Scores = 0;

    Horizontal = 1;
    Vertical = 1;
    
}

void Update()
{
    if (player1Scored)
    {
        Player1Goal();
    }

    if (player2Scored)
    {
        Player2Goal();
    }

    PlayerMovement();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit2D player1Scored = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up),  0.25f, player1Score);
    RaycastHit2D player2Scored = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.left),  0.25f, player2Score);

    RaycastHit2D hitUp = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up),  0.25f, walls);
    RaycastHit2D hitLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.left),  0.25f, walls);
    RaycastHit2D hitDown = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.down),  0.25f, walls);
    RaycastHit2D hitRight = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.right),  0.25f, walls);

    if (hitUp || hitDown)
    {
        Vertical = Vertical * -1;
    }

    if (hitLeft || hitRight)
    {
        Horizontal = Horizontal * -1;
    }
}

public void Player1Goal()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    player1Scores = player1Scores + 1;
    player1Points.text = "Score: " + player1Scores.ToString();
}

public void Player2Goal()
{
    player2Scores = player2Scores + 1;
    player2Points.text = "Score: " + player2Scores.ToString();
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}"""
```

Comment: What happens if you flip the mask to be everything but the score ?

Comment: general note instead of using `transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up)` etc you can simply use `transform.up`, `-transfom.up` etc

Comment: btw for pong it would be enough to simply check for `if(transform.position.x <= player1Score.position.x) { Player2Goal()  } else if (transfom.position.x >= player2Score) { Player1Goal(); }` ... no need for raycatsing really

Comment: Try adding a tilde '~' with the last parameter of Physics2D.Raycast.